# Pandas Group by column and concatenate rows to form a string separated by spaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like:

```py
my_df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1], "word": ["hello", "my", "friend"]})
```

And I would like to group by id and concatenate the word (without changing the order), the result dataset should look like:

[image: Expected result]

Given:

- Dataframe is already sorted by id, words in the desired order

Constraints:

- The the word order should be maintained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have the following dataframe (slighyly modified from yours)

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], "word": ["hello", "my", "friend", "goodbye", "my", "friend"]})
```

**Output**

```
    id  word
0   1   hello
1   1   my
2   1   friend
3   2   goodbye
4   2   my
5   2   friend
```

To get the desired result, use

```
my_df.groupby('id')['word'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

**Output**

```
       id
1      hello my friend
2    goodbye my friend
Name: word, dtype: object
```

This groups each row by your column *id*, then takes each result and uses Pandas [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to join them with a whitespace delimiter.

This is a groupby object, not a dataframe though; to get it back into a useable dataframe, append *reset_index*

```
    my_df.groupby('id')['word'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
    id  word
0   1   hello my friend
1   2   goodbye my friend
```

If the dataframe is rather large, using `apply` may not be the best approach, as it performs the aggregation over every row; there may be faster methods to use. As long as your dataframe isn't tens of thousands of rows, the difference should be negligible.

Answer (score 4):

This is a `.groupby` operation. With pandas you can pass user defined functions, to perform aggregations. In this case you just want to `.join` the grouped elements with a single space.

```
out = my_df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(words=('word', ' '.join))

print(out)
   id            words
0   1  hello my friend
```

- `as_index=False` ensures that `id` remains a column (not the index) after the operation
- `.agg(words=...)` perform an aggregation on each of our groups, creating a new column titled `"words"`

  - `('word', ' '.join)` on the column titled `"word"` from our grouped dataframe, apply the function `' '.join` to the data. Note that you could also write this as `lambda s: ' '.join(s)`, but I decided to go with the less verbose approach.

Comment: `my_df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(words=('word', ' '.join))`  I am getting `words 1`. Did I miss something?

Comment: If you already have a column named `'words'` then `pandas` will add a `1` to keep them from overlapping with each other.